# Extremely high accuracy metrics for tree classifiers

Tags: python, twitter, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am working on a project to classify presidential debate tweets into neutral, positive and negative for each candidate. (Not the current debate dataset). I am training using `Decision trees`, `Decision tree ensemble` and `AdaBoost`. The issue is I am getting the accuracy of 100%, which is extremely weird and impossible.

The data I have is in the form of a `bag-of-words` model. Each word in the vocabulary is represented by 0/1 depending on whether or not the word appears in each tweet. I have included the stats at the end of the question. `df_obama` is a data-frame with all the tweets about Obama.

```
df_Obama = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("../data/Obama_BagOfWords.csv")
df_Obama = df_Obama.reindex(np.random.permutation(df_Obama.index)).reset_index()
dataFeatures = df_Obama[allAttribs_Obama]
targetVar = list(df_Obama['Class'])

splitRatio = 0.9
splitPoint = int(splitRatio*len(dataFeatures))
dataFeatures_train = dataFeatures[:splitPoint]
dataFeatures_test = dataFeatures[splitPoint:]

targetVar_train = targetVar[:splitPoint]
targetVar_test = targetVar[splitPoint:]

clfObj = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clfObj.fit(dataFeatures_train,targetVar_train)
preds = list(clfObj.predict(dataFeatures_test))
accScore = accuracy_score(targetVar_test,preds)
labels = [1,-1,0]

precision = precision_score(targetVar_test,preds,average=None,labels=labels)
recall = recall_score(targetVar_test,preds,average=None,labels=labels)
f1Score = f1_score(targetVar_test,preds,average=None,labels=labels)

print("Overall Acurracy",accScore)
print("precision",precision)
print("recall",recall)
print("f1Score",f1Score)

Overall Acurracy 1.0
precision [ 1.  1.  1.]
recall [ 1.  1.  1.]
f1Score [ 1.  1.  1.]
```

**I just cannot figure out why is this the case? Is there a reason why the metrics are so high?** I also tried with different train-test split ratio and the result seems to be no different.

Note:
Here is the data info:

```
df_Obama.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5465 entries, 0 to 5464
Columns: 13078 entries, level_0 to zzzzzzzzzz
dtypes: int64(13078)
memory usage: 545.3 MB

df_Obama.head(3)
0023Washington  08hayabusa  09Its   .... 09what 1000000th   
0               1           0            1       0
1               0           0            0       0
0               0           0            0       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the classifier can see the target value? Is `df_Obama['Class']` included in the array of features? It is not clear because you do not show the value of `allAttribs_Obama`.

Also check out the [documentation for decision trees on scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tips-on-practical-use), specifically:

> "Decision trees tend to overfit on data with a large number of
>   features."

You might want to try reducing your feature space (check out scikit-learn's [documentation on feature selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)).

On a side note, you can use [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) to create training and testing sets.

Comment: That is a brilliant catch. I was reckless to not check if the `class` was being captured somewhere. Thanks a lot! Now the metrics make much more sense.